# Javascript pause/resume toggle button

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a little challenge with school. We have learned CSS, HTML, and Javascript. I am trying to create a timer that is always running in the background. Then I need a button that pauses said timer and changes into a resume button that will resume the timer. This is what I have come up with.

```
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {

const counterElement = document.getElementById('counter')

let counterValue = 0

const pauseButton = document.getElementById('pause')

const resumeButton = document.getElementById('resume')

const submitButton = document.getElementById(`submit`)

const minusButton = document.getElementById(`minus`)

const plusButton = document.getElementById('plus')

const heartButton = document.getElementById('heart')


intervalId = setInterval(myCallback, 1000);

function myCallback() {
    counterValue += 1;
    counterElement.innerHTML = counterValue;
}

function resume() {
    setInterval(myCallback, 1000);
    pauseButton.style.display = '';
    resumeButton.style.display = 'none';

}

function pause() {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    pauseButton.style.display = 'none';
    resumeButton.style.display = '';

}

pauseButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    pause()
})

resumeButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    resume()
})
```

It does not function properly. Only the first few clicks work.

Answer (score 0):

```
function resume() {
    intervalId = setInterval(myCallback, 1000);
    pauseButton.style.display = '';
    resumeButton.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Try this. The root issue is that you're not assigning your setInterval reference back to your intervalId variable. So when you call clearInterval(intervalId) later, your code is saying, "That's already been cleared..." and not doing anything.

In short, your current resume() function creates a NEW setInterval - it doesn't update the old one. And since there was no reference to the new setInterval, there was no way for your pause function to be able to find it and clear it.

Comment: No problem, if it resolved your issue then please consider marking this as the answer to this question so that it's easier for others with similar problems to find it

Answer (score 0):

When you call `setTimeout` in the `resume` function, you have to reassign the `intervalId` variable to store the new interval ID. If you don't do that, your `pause` function will keep cancelling the first interval, which is a no-op.

So do this instead:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {

  const counterElement = document.getElementById('counter')

  let counterValue = 0

  const pauseButton = document.getElementById('pause')

  const resumeButton = document.getElementById('resume')

  //const submitButton = document.getElementById(`submit`)

  //const minusButton = document.getElementById(`minus`)

  //const plusButton = document.getElementById('plus')

  //const heartButton = document.getElementById('heart')


  //It's a good idea to declare your variables. Since you want to reassign it, you probably want `let`.
  let intervalId = setInterval(myCallback, 1000);

  function myCallback() {
    counterValue += 1;
    counterElement.innerHTML = counterValue;
  }

  function resume() {
    //Assign the new interval ID to `intervalId`
    intervalId = setInterval(myCallback, 1000);
    pauseButton.style.display = '';
    resumeButton.style.display = 'none';

  }

  function pause() {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    pauseButton.style.display = 'none';
    resumeButton.style.display = '';

  }

  pauseButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    pause()
  })

  resumeButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    resume()
  })

})
```

```html
<button id="pause" >Pause</button>
<button id="resume" style="display:none;" >Resume</button>
<div id="counter" >0</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

When you create a new Interval in your resume() function, you need to store its return value again in your intervalId variable for the next time you call pause().